# electron-windows-store: How to correctly specify the data?

Tags: javascript, uwp, windows-store-apps, electron, desktop-bridge

I want to build a UWP application from exe (electron) using the [electron-windows-store package](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/electron-windows-store).

What do I need to specify in the devCert, certPass, desktopConverter?

**devCert.** How do I get a certificate? I went to my account, created the application. Where to take this certificate? If I [correctly understand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/the-app-certification-process) the certificate give after checking the application, but to send the application for verification I need to build it, and for this I need a certificate.

**certPass.** What is it and where to get it?

**desktopConverter.** I found [this app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-run-desktop-app-converter). This is what I need? If yes, which path to specify (this application from the store)

**Update**

I got a certificate using this [manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/create-certificate-package-signing). I've written all the data in the [js file](https://github.com/StekolschikovV/AppX/blob/master/appx.js) to create the application.

After that I ran the command to build the app:

> PS C:\Users\steko\Desktop\AppX> node .\appx.js
>   Configuration:
>   Desktop Converter Location:    C:\desktop-converter-tools
>   Expanded Base Image:           C:\BaseImage.wim
>   Publisher:                     CN=developmentca
>   Dev Certificate:               C:\Users\steko\Desktop\AppX\devcert.pfx
>   Windows Kit Location:          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\bin\x64
>   Starting Conversion...
>   Cleaning pre-appx output folder...
>   Copying data...
>   Creating manifest..
>   Copying visual assets into pre-appx folder...
>   Overwriting manifest...
>   Creating priconfig...
>   events.js:160
>   throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>   ^
>   Error: spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64
>   \makepri.exe ENOENT       at exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
>   at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
>   (internal/child_process.js:193:32)         at onErrorNT
>   (internal/child_process.js:367:16)
>   at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
>   at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)

How to fix the error?

[git](https://github.com/StekolschikovV/AppX)

Answer (score 1):

> devCert. How do I get a certificate? I went to my account, created the
>   application. Where to take this certificate? If I correctly understand
>   the certificate give after checking the application, but to send the
>   application for verification I need to build it, and for this I need a
>   certificate.

According to the document, you could generate a certificate from the CLI tool. The certificate is used to sign the package you create so that you could sideload it on device and test it.

> certPass. What is it and where to get it?

This is the password option for your cert. You could specify it by yourself when you create the certificate via this command.

> desktopConverter. I found this app. This is what I need? If yes, which
>   path to specify (this application from the store)

Yes. You could specify the tool in `C:\\desktop-converter-tools`.

**Update**

> Is there a simple guide or lesson? A video example? I can not understand what exactly I need to do

Yes, you could refer to [**Distribute a packaged desktop app**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-distribute#distribute-your-app-without-placing-it-onto-the-windows-store) official document, And there is  the non-store distribution video example in it.

> Please provide more information about application certification

You could [create your certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/create-certificate-package-signing) and use it to sign your package by [`SignTool.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/sign-app-package-using-signtool).

Comment: Please provide more information about application certification. The Microsoft website has 100500+ articles and tutorials. Is there a simple guide or lesson? A video example? I can not understand what exactly I need to do ... (